# Is there a way to concatenate two IActorRef arrays?

Tags: f#, akka, actor, akka.net

I am learning AKKA.NET using f# but i'm stuck here: Here is the code:

```
// finalArr -> IActorRef array
let mutable neigh:IActorRef[]= [||] // IActorRef array
    for i in [0.. 10] do     
        if i = 0 then
            neigh.[0] <- finalArr.[0]
        elif i = 10-1 then
            neigh.[10-1] <- finalArr.[10-2]
        else
            neigh.[i] <-  [ finalArr.[i-1] ; finalArr.[i+1] ] // Not working
```

I thought of using Array.concatenate but it wont work as it expects Array not IActorRef array.

Comment: I actually figured it out myself by converting the IActorRef array to IActorRefList so operations can be performed easily, and then converting it back to  IActorRef array by creating new new IActorRef array and pushing all the elements in it!

Answer (score 1):

This line gives you a **list** with two arrays inside (assuming `finalArr` is a jagged array):

```
neigh.[i] <- [ finalArr.[i-1] ; finalArr.[i+1] ]
```

You can either use `Array.append`:

```
neigh.[i] <- Array.append finalArr.[i-1] finalArr.[i+1]
```

Or sequence comprehensions to flatten the two arrays you have (note that the literal for arrays uses `[| ... |]` for brackets):

```
neigh.[i] <- [| yield! finalArr.[i-1] ; yield! finalArr.[i+1] |]
```